# Hooking Cocoa API?

Tags: cocoa, macos, hook

I am trying to Hook Cocoa API.

I know cocoa provides a public api for hooking, so it’s possible to hook the system function and retrieve information like the current font settings of the context.

I am also trying to hook that draw api from cocoa.

Can somebody point me to details on how it can be achieved. Or some references which talks about hooking of Cocoa APIs?

By Hooking , I mean "A fundamental technique of getting control over a particular piece of code execution. It provides an straightforward mechanism that can easily alter the operating system's behavior as well as 3rd party products, without having their source code available."

My requirement is, if any application/system is drawing something, then I want those draw instructions should first come to me. Then I cant to store those commands, for some processing later.

Comment: Please describe more specifically what you want to do.

Comment: Added more details. Please le me know if its sufficient enough.

Comment: I have updated question again.

Comment: Rahul, you're still not being specific. What do you want to achieve by “hooking”?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term you are looking for is something like "systemwide code injection," and Cocoa does not provide an API for any such thing. You'd need to take a look at something like [mach_star](https://github.com/rentzsch/mach_star) or [SIMBL](http://www.culater.net/software/SIMBL/SIMBL.php). But honestly, this is one of those things where, if you have to ask, it's probably a little advanced for you. Modifying other processes' code is a gigantic PITA and even harder to do right, even with as much help as mach_star offers. If you want to see just how hard, take a look at [Unsanity's site](http://unsanity.com/). That's the company that pioneered code injection on OS X, and their entire product line is based around it — and many of their programs are still not compatible with OS X 10.6.

Comment: Thank you Chuck.Yes you got it right. 
I am looking for some tutorials and samples. Even a simple sample to -drawRect() would do. 

Also is it possible to break UI in to peaces. Say some portion is using OpenGl to draw, or some portion is using animation, some Cocoa, how can we get these information?

Comment: @Rahul, you basically have to tailor your injection to every application. *Every single one.* If anyone ever releases a new application, you're screwed. If any application ever changes its UI in any way, you're screwed. If it uses Core Graphics or OpenGL, you're screwed. **There is no way to intercept all of an application's drawing at the vector level.** *None. At all. Really.* You need to look at something else, such as taking screenshots, or abandon your product idea entirely if it absolutely requires the vectors for some reason.

Comment: @Rahul: For one, that's using X11, not OS X technologies like Cocoa and Quartz. For another, that's just transmitting screen images and input events, not directly modifying applications' memory spaces. An app like that can be written using only public OS X functions (specifically, a simple combination of the Quartz Window Services API and the CGEvent APIs would get you most of the way there).

Answer (score 2):

The words you choose and the very broad scope they cover suggest you need to start at the very beginning. There is a simple Cocoa Application [tutorial here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCTutorial/01Introduction/01Introduction.html). It walks you through the basic process of creating a Cocoa application for the Mac. Start there, then post more specific questions as they arise.

Comment: I feel you got me wrong! I know cocoa application development. I am doing it from past 3 years. My requirement is, if any application/system is drawing something, then I cant those draw instructions should first come to me.

Comment: Ah. Now I get what you're asking. Chuck beat me to it buut I agree: it's possible with code injection but this is a difficult path that is far more trouble than it's worth. It might be worth updating your question to detail what specifically you want to intercept drawing to *do*. There may be an alternative.

Comment: Added comment to Chuck's post.

Answer (score 1):

Including...

```
#import <objc/objc.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>
```

will allow you to have access to modifying the classes and objects at runtime. Although this is rather 'reckless.'

A much better Idea is to use [Objective-C Categories](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW1) for a more 'safe' access.

Comment: Please read the comment just added to Joshua reply. Thus I feel we also cannot take this as answers. :)

Comment: @Rahul, if you want to override the draw instructions, take a look at [Ray Wenderlichs tutorials about drawing your own objects.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2134/core-graphics-101-glossy-buttons)

Comment: That's about implementing a custom view, not intercepting another application's drawing.

Comment: Sorry, Stephen as Peter said, that's about implementing a custom view, not intercepting another application's drawing.

Answer (score 1):

You can't intercept another application's drawing as it happens, but you can capture the results after the fact. Use [Quartz Window Services](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CGWindow_Reference/) to take screenshots, and [Quartz Display Services](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/) to find out when the screen gets updated.

Comment: Thank you peter. I had done this in past. And I believe Code injection is what I am looking for. I am looking for some tutorials and samples. Even a simple -drawRect() would do.