# How to monitor global use of OSX application services?

Tags: macos, service, monitor, nsevent

Open a TextEdit document with a few words in it. Notice that when you right click on a word, you can click "Look up (Word)" to get its definition or "Speech Start Speaking" to hear it read out aloud.

How can I build a local application to monitor globally whenever a user has requested a dictionary definition or the speech synthesizer?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ways I can think of are

1. injection and Hooking. If its cocoa application you can also try swizzling. I think with this approach its very easy to manage what you are trying to do. But it can be lot of work.
2. If you follow apple techniques so they must be sending notification that can be catch between applications. Try to find them and you are done.

Comment: hmm.. can you go into more detail?

Comment: Your question is very vague. What kind of detail you need. I guess you should to study about the points I have mentioned in here first.

Comment: 1. From the discussion here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254692/hooking-cocoa-api im guessing hooking is near impossible to do for a noob like me.
2. What exactly are the apple techniques you are talking about that catch notifications from the Dictionary or Speech Synthesizer?

Comment: As I said, apple makes use of Notifications. Check NSNotificationCenter and NSWorkSpace, so I am sure that there must be some notification they must be raising which can be caught by you.