# Detect global paste events in cocoa

Tags: cocoa, hook, paste

within my app I'd like to know when something is pasted from the clipboard, even if it does not happen in my application. So if a copy happens in let's say Safari and the paste is happening in let's say TextEdit, then I'd like to get a notification of that in my own application. Is this anyhow possible?

I found two articles on hooking API calls on Mac OS
[Is it possible to hook API calls on Mac OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689348/is-it-possible-to-hook-api-calls-on-mac-os)
 and 
[Hooking Cocoa API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254692/hooking-cocoa-api)
but i have no idea if this can help me.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can observe the keyboard input using [Quartz Event Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html) or [Carbon Event Manager](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/Carbon_Event_Manager_Ref/Reference/reference.html).
Note that sandboxing your app will break this feature.

Comment: Of course, Paste could be invoked by a menu rather than a keystroke.